# Update role with aspnet membership provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I have a RadioButtonList "chklRoles" which has 4 buttons. I want to update database aspnet_UserInRoles if I select a role. But it seems that the Aspnet Membership Provider doesn't have an update method. How can I do it?

```
 protected void chklRoles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string role in Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName))
        {
            if (chklRoles.Items.FindByText(role).Selected == true)
            {  
                // update role;
               // Roles.DeleteRole("origin_role");
               //  Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, role);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: I think that to delete it and add it with a new role maybe an option. But please give me an advice.
update: each user only can have one role. What I want is how to switch roles by clicking the radio button. Update meants a new role will replace the older role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) to add or remove roles from a user. You'll have to determine what roles are to be added and/or removed. That would look something like this:

```
protected void chklRoles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var current = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName);
    var added = new List<string>();
    var removed = new List<string>();

    // go over all the roles to build the lists 
    foreach (string role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
    {
        if (chklRoles.Items.FindByText(role).Selected && !current.Contains( role ))
        {  
            added.Add( role );
        }
        else if( current.Contains( role ) )
        {
            removed.Add( role );
        }
    }
    // apply changes if needed
    if( added.Count > 0 )
    {
       Roles.AddUsersToRoles( new[]{userName}, added.ToArray());
    }
    if( removed.Count > 0 )
    {
        Roles.RemoveUsersFromRoles(new[]{userName}, removed.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't had a chance to check this code thoroughly.

Comment: Ah, right. From your code it wasn't clear you are using radio buttons. At any rate, this code should do the job, though you might want to tune it to enforce the one-role-per-user policy.